# is there any parallelism in single node hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, mahout

i'm newer in hadoop. and i could run mahout example in single node hadoop.
is there any parallelism in single node hadoop? (for example in jobs, chunks, )
(hadoop works faster than WEKA in my workload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode you are referring to is same as pseudo-distributed mode. This is a one node cluster. In this you have a namenode, a jobtracker, and a single datanode and tasktracker running. You can verify with "jps" command.

By default a tasktracker can run up to two map and reduce tasks in parallel (mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum), so you will actually see some concurrency on your one machine.

Comment: ok thanks. whats the mean of mapred.max.split.size ? when i use more partition, time of executing job is different each time. it has a optimum value for related to volume of datasets.

Comment: A split here refers to chunks of data that a mapper works on. By default the split size is equal to the block size of 64M. It can be found in hdfs-core.xml file. Coming to mapred.max.split.size is the maximum bytes that a mapper can ever get for processing. The unit of mapred.max.split.size is bytes.